# Multiple Joins WIth JPA2

Tags: java, jpa-2.0

I'm trying to get to grips with JPA2 and attempting to do a couple of joins to get me a single result.  Here's what I've tried at the moment:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<FileCollection> cq = cb.createQuery(getEntityClass()); // getEntityClass() will return FileCollection.class

Root<FileCollection> collectionRoot = cq.from(getEntityClass());
Join<FileCollection, Repository> repositories = collectionRoot.join(FileCollection_.repository);
Join<Repository, Customer> customers = repositories.join(Repository_.customer);

cq.select(collectionRoot);
cq.where(cb.equal(customers.get(Customer_.name), customerName),
    cb.equal(repositories.get(Repository_.name), repositoryName) ,
    cb.equal(collectionRoot.get(FileCollection_.folderName), folderName)
);

return getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getSingleResult();
```

This isn't working though.  If I comment out the 2nd & 3rd parameters of the where call, it works (so I'd be providing just a customer name).  So I'm getting something wrong.  I just don't know what!  Here's the query I'm trying to achieve expressed as SQL:

```sql
SELECT f.*
FROM filecollection f
JOIN repository r ON f.REPOSITORY_ID = r.REPOSITORY_ID
JOIN customer c ON r.CUSTOMER_ID = c.CUSTOMER_ID
WHERE c.NAME = 'X' AND r.NAME = 'Y' AND f.FOLDER_NAME = 'Z';
```

Can anyone help me out and point out my mistake.  In the meanwhile, I'll go back to my JPA2 book and see if I can figure this out!

Comment: A NoResultsException.  The parameters that I am passing are correct though so I do expect to get results if I get my query correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be like this:

```
cq.where(cb.and(cb.equal(customers.get(Customer_.name), customerName),
                cb.equal(repositories.get(Repository_.name), repositoryName) ,
                cb.equal(collectionRoot.get(FileCollection_.folderName), folderName)
));
```

Comment: That's no changed the outcome.  It still returns no results when I believe it shouldn't.

Comment: What's the resulting SQL query look like?

Comment: I just turned on the Hibernate logging and as I did I noticed my mistake.  Your solution is correct - I just can't type!  Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Good. To be honest I have never used JPA2